# retrieve results of 2 table using JOIN failed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `names` and `phones` I did this for the query

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY fname ASC 
        RIGHT JOIN phones ON phones.id=names.phone_id"
        );
```

I got `$result` as false. My names table has a column named phone_id and it's a PK of `phones`'s id, like so

```
names
- phone_id (FK)

phones
- id (PK)
```

What's wrong with my sql above?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax should go like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM names
RIGHT JOIN phones ON phones.id = names.phone_id
ORDER BY fname ASC
```

The `ORDER BY` had to be moved to the end.

Answer (score 1):

`Order by` should be the last part of your query

```
SELECT * 
   FROM names n
   RIGHT JOIN phones p ON p.id=n.phone_id
   ORDER BY fname ASC
```

Start using `alias` names to make the query more readable

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ORDER BY` as last clause of your query. Becasue order by i.e. sorting works at last after fetch.

```
SELECT * 
FROM names as n
RIGHT JOIN phones as p ON p.id=n.phone_id
ORDER BY fname ASC
```

To see more abour ORDER BY you can check the manual [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)